# HP tx2510us shuts down without warning, now won't boot, no BIOS codes, screen doesn't light

Tags: boot, tablet

HP tx2510us worked great for a year and a half, rarely it would shut down instead of sleeping. It started running hot sometimes, I installed Win7, worked great, still running hot. Before Xmas, it gave me evidence of video errors - jagged lines, rows missing. That same night, it started rebooting, then it shut off and wouldn't boot. It gave me a BIOS code, I shut it off to look up the code online. When I turned it on again, it won't boot at all. The LEDs all light up, the fan, HD, and optical all spin up, but the screen never lights up and it doesn't try to boot, nor does it blink any BIOS codes. It just acts like it's sleeping, and won't wake up.

I suspected heat problems, so I disassembled it, cleaned the crap out of the fan, and reassembled it, breaking the stereo mic connector. Oh well. When I reassembled it, it booted up into Win7 again, but kept shutting down for no discernible reason. After a dozen or so random reboots like that, it is now back to where it was - turns on but doesn't boot or give BIOS codes. The screen never lights, and everything spins up then idles.

Any ideas? I really can't afford to buy a new one and I use(d) it to take ALL my notes, that's why I got a tablet in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

This might sound weird but it will work. Power up your pc, make sure it stays on, even though you don't get a screen display.

Wrap your PC in a thick towel or a blanket and let it sit and overheat until it shuts off on it's own.

Let it cool for about half an hour, then boot it up and see if it works.

Comment: I tried to to keep it on for an hour, wrapped under the towel, and after it got shut down automatically, I waited for it cool down and restarted — and OMG it worked. Don't use the Quick Launch button on the screen: It also triggers the problem.

Comment: That sounds really weird, but since it worked.... can you explain why?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a Pavilion tx2150us ... is it a Pavilion tx2510us or a tx2120us?

At any rate it sounds like it was overheating and damaged your motherboard or processor, with the video errors you mentioned I would say most likely the motherboard is gone. You can try removing the hard drive to recover your data, but the notebook will probably have to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Some HP troubleshooting documents for that model here

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/documentSubCategory?tmp_rule=16843&tmp_task=solveCategory&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&tool=&query=HP%20tx2510us&product=3747931

.

You might shoot an email to these guys, include the model number and symptoms, see what they say about repairing that model

http://cgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=260674058980